# PHP- how to get values from checked checkboxes and corresponding textboxes

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox, textbox

I want to get three values separated by a comma when the form is submitted. The value from the checkbox, textbox 1 and textbox 2.

This is my code that retrieves values from mysql database and generates checkboxes and two corresponding textboxes.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM subject";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
$s = $row['sub'];
echo $s;
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="req_sub[]" value= "<?php echo $s; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $s; ?>" placeholder="Total Number" />
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $s; ?>" placeholder="Pass Number" />     

<?php 
} 
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

[image: This is how my form looks --]

Suppose the user checks the first three boxes , and enters the values like in this picture - [image]

when I click add, I get the values -- 
Physics
Math
Chemistry
by using the code below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['req_sub'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['req_sub'] as $selected) {
            echo $selected."</br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

but how do I get the values like this-
 
Physics,40,30
Math,40,30
Chemistry,30,25

I want this output in a variable so that I can store it in my database table.
I have spent several hours behind this in last few days. Please help me with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you need to assign unique names to the `<input type="text" ... />` so you can recieve its values in the `PHP`.
2. Second, you need to write `PHP` code, that's concatenating those values.

For example, your `HTML` code might be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="req_sub[]" value= "<?php echo $s; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="total[<?php echo $s; ?>]" placeholder="Total Number" />
<input type="text" name="pass[<?php echo $s; ?>]" placeholder="Pass Number" />
```

and your `PHP` code might be:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['req_sub'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['req_sub'] as $selected) {
            $total = $_POST['total'][$selected];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'][$selected];
            $var = $selected . ',' . $total . ',' . $pass;
            echo $var . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Saroar, you are welcome. Btw, if your `$s` might contain a double quotes when you get it from database, you also need to escape it via `htmlspecialchars($s)` when you insertig it in the `html`. So, you will get something like this: `<input type="checkbox" name="req_sub[]" value= "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($s); ?>" />`